# Run code when approving members

Tags: umbraco7

Is it possible to execute some C# code when checking the "Is Approved" checkbox for a Member?

Our site has a registration form which programmatically creates a user in the Members section, however the new Members must be approved by an admin and we would like to send an email to the Member when they are approved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you will need to do is look at `MemberService.Saving` and `MemberService.Saved` events and attach a custom event handler. See [Determining if an entity is new](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Events-v6/determining-new-entity) for information on determining if you are dealing with a new or existing member. Below is copied from documentation:

In v6.2+ and 7.1+ you can use the extension method on any implementation of IEntity (which is nearly all models returned by the Umbraco Services):

```
var isNew = entity.IsNewEntity();
```

**How it works**

This is all possible because of the `IRememberBeingDirty` interface. Indeed the name of this interface is hilarious but it describes exactly what it does. All entities implement this interface which is extremely handy as it tracks not only the property data that has changed (because it inherits from yet another hilarious interface called `ICanBeDirty`) but also the property data that was changed before it was committed.

From here you should be able to check the property data you are interested in and send your email accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will get me what I needed.